# Jekyll max excerpt length

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to get a an excerpt of my posts to serve as the description meta tag on my page. Is there any way to limit the excerpt characters to 156?

Here is my current code:

```
{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `truncate` filter:

```
{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 156 }}
```

Comment: For anyone finding this via Google, you may also want to know about the `truncatewords` filter, which truncates by word count instead of by character count. It's nice if you don't want your excerpt to end in the middle of a word. https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncatewords/